# Find missing contact date details

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with Contacts details:

Table: `tblContacts`

```
CREATE TABLE tblContacts
(
    Series INT,
    ContacNumber INT,
    CDate DATETIME
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,123456,'2019-01-01');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(3,3456,'2019-01-01');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,123560,'2019-01-02');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,123459,'2019-01-05');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(3,3446,'2019-01-02');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(3,3486,'2019-01-03');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(3,34861,'2019-01-05');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(3,34862,'2019-01-07');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,127456,'2019-01-21');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,129456,'2019-02-03');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(12,126456,'2019-02-06');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(94,941256,'2019-01-01');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(94,944356,'2019-01-03');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(94,941356,'2019-01-07');
INSERT INTO tblContacts VALUES(94,943356,'2019-01-09');
```

I want to find those contacts who never called on those dates and 1 or 2 days before and after call.

**Note**: I may crease before and after calls to any level like 1,2,3,4 so on.

**Expected Output**: The following output for just 1 day before and after calls.

```
ContacNumber    CDate
----------------------------------------
3486            2019-01-03
NULL            2019-01-04
34861           2019-01-05
NULL            2019-01-06
34862           2019-01-07
123560          2019-01-02
NULL            2019-01-03 - 2019-01-04
123459          2019-01-05
NULL            2019-01-06 - 2019-01-20
127456          2019-01-21
NULL            2019-01-22 - 2019-02-02
129456          2019-02-03
NULL            2019-02-04 - 2019-02-05
126456          2019-02-06
941256          2019-01-01
NULL            2019-01-02
944356          2019-01-03
NULL            2019-01-04 - 2019-01-06
941356          2019-01-07
NULL            2019-01-08
943356          2019-01-09
```

**My try**: Following query works only for 1 day before and after calls but not for other than 1.

Query:

```
; WITH Stage_1_CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Series,
            ContacNumber,
            CAST(CDate AS DATE) CDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Series ORDER BY CAST(CDate AS DATE)) rnk1,
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Series ORDER BY CAST(CDate AS DATE)))/2 rnk2,
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Series ORDER BY CAST(CDate AS DATE)) + 1)/2 rnk3
    FROM tblContacts
    GROUP BY ContacNumber,CDate,Series
)
,
Stage_2_CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN rnk1%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rnk1%2=0 THEN CDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY Series,rnk2) 
                ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rnk1%2=1 THEN CDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY Series,rnk3)
           END AS CDate_Prev,
           CASE WHEN rnk1%2=1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN rnk1%2=0 THEN CDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY Series,rnk3) 
                ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN rnk1%2=1 THEN CDate END) OVER (PARTITION BY Series,rnk2)
           END AS CDate_Next
    FROM Stage_1_CTE
) 
,Stage_Final_CTE AS
(
    SELECT c.Series,
           c.ContacNumber, 
           c.CDate, 
           EndDate = ''
    FROM Stage_2_CTE c
    WHERE c.CDate <> DATEADD(DAY, +1, CDate_Prev) OR c.CDate <> DATEADD(DAY, -1, CDate_Next)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Series,
           ContacNumber = NULL,
           CDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.CDate),
           EndDate = ' - '+CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, CDate_Next) AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM Stage_2_CTE c
    WHERE c.CDate <> DATEADD(DAY, -1, CDate_Next)
)
SELECT  ContacNumber, 
        CASE WHEN CAST(CDate AS VARCHAR(10)) =  REPLACE(EndDate,' - ','')  
        THEN CAST(CDate AS VARCHAR(10))
        ELSE
            CAST(CDate AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(EndDate AS VARCHAR(13))
        END CDate
FROM Stage_Final_CTE
GROUP BY ContacNumber,CDate,EndDate,Series
ORDER BY Series,CDate;
```

Comment: Can you try editing the question using a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm struggling to understand the question a little bit. Are you asking how you can collect data for 2 days before and after a specified date in your supplied data above?

Comment: "I want to find those contacts who never called on those dates and 1 or 2 days before and after call."  On WHAT dates?  If contacts are in the table, then presumably they called on that date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I mean to say those dates which are missing from table, For example I need to generate all dates between start and end dates for each series and then find out the missing dates as shown in the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate numbers and then add in rows.  Something like this:

```
select contactnumber, cdate, 1 as isvalid
from tblcontacts
union all
select c.contactnumber, dateadd(day, v.n, c.contacctdate), 0
from tblcontacts c cross join
     (values (-1), (1)) v(n)
where not exists (select 1
                  from tblcontacts c2
                  where c2.contactnumber = c.contactnumber and
                        c2.date = dateadd(day, v.n, c.contacctdate)
                 );
```

Note:  I added a new column to determine if the row is valid.  It doesn't make sense to repeat `NULL` values in the first column, because you don't know what contact number the row applies to.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the next date in a `Series`.

Which can be used to find the gaps between the dates.

Then glue those gaps to the result.

For Sql Server 2008 the data is first loaded into a temporary table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpContacts', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmpContacts; 

CREATE TABLE #tmpContacts
(
 Series INT NOT NULL,
 Rn INT NOT NULL,
 ContacNumber INT NOT NULL,
 CDate DATE NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (Series, Rn)
); 

INSERT INTO #tmpContacts (Series, ContacNumber, CDate, Rn)
SELECT Series, ContacNumber
, CAST(CDate AS DATE)
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Series ORDER BY CAST(CDate AS DATE)) Rn
FROM tblContacts
WHERE CDate >=  CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)
    AND CAST(CDate AS DATE) <=  EOMONTH(EOMONTH(CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)))
  GROUP BY Series, ContacNumber, CAST(CDate AS DATE);

WITH CTE_CONTACTS AS
(
  SELECT Series, ContacNumber
  , CDate
  , CDate AS nextCDate
  , CAST(0 AS BIT) AS IsGap
  FROM #tmpContacts

  UNION ALL

  SELECT t1.Series, null
  , DATEADD(day,1,t1.CDate)
  , DATEADD(day,-1,t2.CDate)
  , 1
  FROM #tmpContacts t1
  LEFT JOIN #tmpContacts t2
    ON t2.Series = t1.Series
   AND t2.Rn = t1.Rn + 1
   AND t1.CDate < DATEADD(day,-1,t2.CDate)
)
SELECT c.Series, ContacNumber
, CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar,c.CDate,23), 
        CASE 
        WHEN c.IsGap=1
         AND DATEDIFF(day,c.CDate,c.nextCDate) > 0 
        THEN ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar,c.nextCDate,23) 
        END) AS Cdates
FROM CTE_CONTACTS c
ORDER BY c.Series, c.CDate;
```

Test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/BPA93166)

In Sql Server 2012+ the window function `LEAD` can be used instead.

```
WITH CTE_CONTACTS AS
(
  SELECT Series, ContacNumber
  , CAST(CDate AS DATE) AS CDate
  , LEAD(CAST(CDate AS DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY Series ORDER BY CAST(CDate AS DATE)) AS nextCDate
  FROM tblContacts
  WHERE CDate >=  CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)
    AND CAST(CDate AS DATE) <=  EOMONTH(EOMONTH(CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)))
  GROUP BY Series, ContacNumber, CAST(CDate AS DATE)
)
, CTE_CONTACTS2 AS
(
  SELECT Series, ContacNumber
  , CDate
  , nextCDate
  , CAST(0 AS BIT) AS IsGap
  FROM CTE_CONTACTS

  UNION ALL

  SELECT Series, null
   , DATEADD(day,1,CDate)
   , DATEADD(day,-1,nextCDate)
   , 1
  FROM CTE_CONTACTS c
  WHERE CDate < DATEADD(day,-1,nextCDate)
)
SELECT c.Series, ContacNumber
, CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar,c.CDate,23), 
        CASE 
        WHEN c.IsGap=1 
         AND DATEDIFF(day,c.CDate,c.nextCDate) > 0 
        THEN ' - ' + CONVERT(varchar,c.nextCDate,23) 
        END) AS Cdates
FROM CTE_CONTACTS2 c
ORDER BY c.Series, c.CDate;
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/MFP65544)

Comment: Is there ‘LEAD’ function in SQL server 2008 r2?

Comment: @MAK Updated with a solution that I assume could work in mssql 2008 r2. But don't have a 2008 version to test it on.  So give it a try.

Comment: I have made some changes in your query, Looks almost complete, Just want to get 1/2/3...n number of data before/after `NULL` contactNumber.https://rextester.com/NDMTZ31670

Comment: That n number will be input from user to get before and after records, we can have input variable name `@BeforeAfterValue` to get result accordingly. Right now I am getting all values before and after nulls.